# Datatable : Highlight a different cell from the others on a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable

I would like on the same line to find the cell different from the others and to highlight it by a CSS class. Here is what I would like to do:

[image]

What I don't know is how to find the different data, I think I have to loop the line but then I get stuck.

[JsFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b9qkevsa/)

```
function constructRaws(data) {
    var raws = [];
    $.each(data, function(i, value) {
        $.each(value, function(ind, val){
            console.log(val);
            value[ind] = "<span>"+val+"</span>" + "<span class='tdtooltip' style='display:none'>"+ val +"<span class='spid' style='display:none'>0</span></span>";
            if (typeof val === "object"){
                value[ind] = "<span>"+val[0]+"</span>" + "<span class='tdtooltip' style='display:none'>"+ obj_to_string(val) + "<span class='spid' style='display:none'>"+ val[1] +"</span></span>";
            }
        });
         raws.push($.extend(value, {service: i}));   
    });
    return raws;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle works, I'm confused?

Comment: Sorry, I modified the jsfiddle to give an example of what I want. But I would like this to be done dynamically, I change my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b9qkevsa/